# Improve performance while serving video from my microservice

Tags: amazon-s3, video, streaming

So I have an app that after some calculations it returns something like this:

```
{
 ....
  "url": "https://amazons3bucketurl.com/myvideo.mp4"
 ....
}
```

The URL property being a public and valid path to a MP4 video we have lying at an S3 bucket in Amazon.

The problem I have with this is that although I have a good connection and I do not have any problems with the video playback that our mobile app performs, as soon as the connection of the client is less than desirable then the video takes a lot to load and it stutters while loading ( even though we have compressed the video to almost 500kb ).

Also, there is like a second of delay after I click "Play" and the video actually starts playing.

What approach can I take to make the playback smoother?